# Plugin log files not being written

Tags: shopware

- Using Shopware 5.4.6 in production mode.
- Debug plugin is installed and active.

There is a plugin that writes its own log files to the var/log/ folder, so I know the folder is writable by php, but no plugin_production-...log files are being written.

Log files are still being written on my staging copy of this site with the same code but running in dev mode.

Is this perhaps something to do with the mode I'm running in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the default configuration: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.4/engine/Shopware/Configs/Default.php#L263

The logging lever is changed according to your environment. You can change it via config.php and override the default-parameters.

btw: the debug plugin is outdated, you should use the profiler for debugging purposes: https://github.com/FriendsOfShopware/FroshProfiler

Comment: Ah! I suspected there was a per-environment variation, but I didn't know where to look. That the debug plugin is outdated is I guess an unofficial thing? I've not heard this before.

Comment: Not oficially outdated - but it isn't updated since a long time and the dumping of debug variables is a problem on various servers, because the response header gets too big and the browser won't display your page any more. The profiler is a much better way to get variables and other debug information.